# Как правильно заполнить ListBox из XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как правильно заполнить ListBox, чтобы потом можно было адекватно извлекать его items.

Например если добавить элементы таким образом(который опишу ниже), их нельзя будет адекватно извлечь, я имею ввиду имя айтемы. В случае, который написал ниже, при свойстве selectitem, записывает не то что нужно, а нужно только имя айтема

```
<ListBox Name="lb1" >
            <TextBlock>xxx</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>zzz</TextBlock>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Правильный способ не мешать в кучу данные и их отображение. Чтобы дать более подробный ответ нужно узнать чуть больше подробностей о том, что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Заполнить свойство ItemsSource.

Считаю правильным использование паттерна-mvvm.
1. Установить свойство DataContext у:
    * ListBox
    * Контейнера ListBox или любого другого контейнера, в который входит нужный ListBox.
2. В Xaml установить привязку ( Binding ):
   {Binding} или {Binding Имя}

Примечание:
Можно использовать простой массив, тогда необходимо реализовать интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged. Если так сделать, то есть != 0 вероятность того что не всегда сработает. Рекомендую воспользоваться ObservableCollection. С ним такие проблемы не возникнут. Визуальную составляющую редактировать с помощью стилей.

Comment: Если так сделать, то я не смогу удалять элементы listBox.Items.RemoveAt():

Comment: @SOFL, а вы удаляйте из того, что присвоили ItemSource.

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто, нужно импортировать неймспейс для системных типов

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

и тогда в разметке можно заполнить ListBox обычными строками

```
<ListBox>
    <System:String>Первый</System:String>
    <System:String>Второй</System:String>
    <System:String>Третий</System:String>
    <System:String>Четвертый</System:String>
</ListBox>
```

В качестве SelectedItem будет выбранная строка.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> {"xxx", "yyy", "zzz"};
lb1.ItemsSource = strings;
```

А если надо будет удалить какой-нибудь элемент, то:

```
// Удалить "yyy"
strings.Remove("yyy");
```

Comment: Такой вариант не будет работать ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
(lb1.Items[0] as TextBlock).Text = "xxx1";
(lb1.Items[1] as TextBlock).Text = "zzz1";
```

Попробуйте вот так.  У меня работает =/